# phpwebsockets yii implementation

Tags: php, html, yii, websocket, yii-extensions

I am trying to implement websocket using php and as an extension for yii so that i can create a notification like feature for my web application

The code from below link is my starting point:

http://www.flynsarmy.com/2012/02/php-websocket-chat-application-2-0/

Its works perfectly in my local xampp..

I tried converting it as a Yii extension Steps that i followed..

1. I have put the class PHPWebSocket.php in the yii extension folder..
2. I created a controller websocket and a action startserver and a action index(for the chat interface to test out the example from the above link)

here is the code snippet

```
<?php

Yii::import("ext.websocket.PHPWebSocket");

class WebSocketController extends Controller {

    public $layout = '//layouts/empty';

    public function actionStartServer() {

        set_time_limit(0);

        function wsOnMessage($clientID, $message, $messageLength, $binary) {
            global $Server;
            $ip = long2ip($Server->wsClients[$clientID][6]);

            // check if message length is 0
            if ($messageLength == 0) {
                $Server->wsClose($clientID);
                return;
            }

            //The speaker is the only person in the room. Don't let them feel lonely.
            if (sizeof($Server->wsClients) == 1)
                $Server->wsSend($clientID, "There isn't anyone else in the room, but I'll still listen to you. --Your Trusty Server");
            else
            //Send the message to everyone but the person who said it
                foreach ($Server->wsClients as $id => $client)
                    if ($id != $clientID)
                        $Server->wsSend($id, "Visitor $clientID ($ip) said \"$message\"");
        }

// when a client connects
        function wsOnOpen($clientID) {
            global $Server;
            $ip = long2ip($Server->wsClients[$clientID][6]);

            $Server->log("$ip ($clientID) has connected.");

            //Send a join notice to everyone but the person who joined
            foreach ($Server->wsClients as $id => $client)
                if ($id != $clientID)
                    $Server->wsSend($id, "Visitor $clientID ($ip) has joined the room.");
        }

// when a client closes or lost connection
        function wsOnClose($clientID, $status) {
            global $Server;
            $ip = long2ip($Server->wsClients[$clientID][6]);

            $Server->log("$ip ($clientID) has disconnected.");

            //Send a user left notice to everyone in the room
            foreach ($Server->wsClients as $id => $client)
                $Server->wsSend($id, "Visitor $clientID ($ip) has left the room.");
        }

        $Server = new PHPWebSocket();
        $Server->bind('message', 'wsOnMessage');
        $Server->bind('open', 'wsOnOpen');
        $Server->bind('close', 'wsOnClose');

        $Server->wsStartServer('127.0.0.1', 9300);
    }

    public function actionIndex() {
        $this->render('index');
    }

}
```

Is my approach to creating a websocket using php is correct or is it impossible to do so..

I want to implement the same using php only because i am preferred to use node.js or any other scripts

Comment: Can you run a command line app instead? If so, running your server that way may keep your server going longer ...

Comment: You can't start websocket server from a client request within controller. You should run server from command line and keep running continuously.

Comment: Hi @fuzionpro I saw this tutorial about websocket with php and I want to implement this in yii . Have you found a solution how to integrate this with yii . thanks

Comment: @HADEV i was not able to implement websockets but instead used http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/329/real-time-display-of-server-push-data-using-server-sent-events-sse/

Answer (score 1):

When using PHP with Apache, each request to PHP (usually) creates new process/thread. As web sockets are (somewhat) permanent connections, these PHP requests last for quite some time. Each process takes memory on the server. So, as I think this is possible, your server can probably just crash or reject requests if you would have many (or even not so many) users online at one time.

Node.js approach is different - each connection does not require separate process and so it can process many active connections at once.

You could use Node.js together with PHP connecting those two using queues or some other communication mechanism.

Comment: the problem for not preferring node.js is that i am using shared hosting

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else stumbles upon this.

I was looking for a way to implement real-time-events to a Yii application myself.

In the comments above [this (Yii) tutorial on HTML5 SSE](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/329/real-time-display-of-server-push-data-using-server-sent-events-sse/) is mentioned. As it seems to be very easy, it's just not enough if you need to support older browsers and mobile devices.

> **Browser support aka does it work in IE?**    Internet Explorer and Android browser (all versions) don't support Server-Sent Events out of
>   the box. Neither do older versions of Firefox (< 6), Chrome (< 6),
>   Safari (< 5), iOS Safari (< 4), or Opera (< 11).

Another solution is a fairly new [Yii node socket](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-node-socket/) extension. It's based on the node.js socket.io library and uses [elephant.io](http://elephant.io/) to communicate with the server through php. Above all, the extension seems (I've only been using it for a month) to be well written. It has both Linux and Windows support, uses CLI to execute commands and it even has it's own database driver provided.

Other solutions are still welcome.